# Clone directories

Tags: directory-structure, active-directory

I have certain directory path like this `/backup/data/cm/au` and `/backup/data/cm/ds`. I have to create paths from `/cm/au` and `cm/ds` in `tmp` with same owner and group of their originals.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, but it looks like you want something like

```
# cd /backup/data
# cp -a cm /tmp
```

If you don't want to copy all of the `cm` directory, do

```
# cd /backup/data
# cp -a cm/au cm/ds /tmp
```

The `-a` option tells `cp` to preserve as much meta-data as possible. 
For it to preserve ownership (rather than make the copies owned by you),
you must run this as `root` (e.g., run it under `sudo`).

(`-a` also implies `-R`; i.e., recursive copy.)